# ContentProvider bulkInsert nested transaction, insert and update needed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I implemented ContentProvider `bulkInsert()` method to insert large numbers of rows in a table inside a transaction, but after that i need to make an update in a different table and i only want to do that if the bulk insert was committed. The 2 operations need to be atomic, both do or none do, how can i do it ?

This is the bulkInsert method:

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values){

    int nrInserted = 0;
    String TABLE;

    int uriType = mUriMatcher.match(uri);


    switch (uriType){
        case FEEDS:
            TABLE = FeedsProviderContract.TABLE_NAME;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown URI: " + uri );
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //Begin inner transaction
    db.beginTransaction();

    try {

        for (ContentValues cv : values){

            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE, null, cv);

            nrInserted++;
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);

    } catch (SQLException ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    return nrInserted;
 }
```

Now when i call it can i make a outer transaction like this ? I guess it doesn't work.

```
...

//Begin outer transaction

getContentResolver().getContentProvider().bulkInsert(...);

//Update the other table

//End  outer Transaction
```

Comment: Are you saying that if both operations are in the same transaction, it does not work?

Comment: @DFord no that's not that, i don't' know the behavior of Sqlite transactions so imagine this: the inner transaction commits but the outer transaction rollback, will the inner transaction know and rollback too ? If the inner transaction rollback the outer transaction knows and rollbacks too ? That's what i'm asking, but after search a little more i think what i need is `ApplyBatch` because i'm making CRUD operations in different tables.

Comment: Why do you need two transactions in the outer transaction?

Comment: @DFord I'am not following you, two transactions in the outer transaction ? I have one transaction inside bulkInsert that deals with inserts in 1 table, but if i need to make another operation like an update in other table i don't want to put that operation inside bulkInsertmethod so to make those atomic, how do i do it ? That's way i have an outer transaction surrounding bulkInsert and Update, but i don't know if it works, because of what i've describe in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i needed was ApplyBatch and not BulkInsert, it now works how i want.